# Python: Make sure concurrent Thread is finished

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a python program that works with threads. I'm using concurrent.futures to handle the threads. In the programm one thread should create an PDF-File. Because this task is lasting very long I want to create a thread to handle the creation. But after sometime I want to work with the pdf file again. Therefore, I have to be sure, that the previous thread is finished.

My question is, how can I check if my concurrent future thread is finished or how I can wait on its execution.

**Code**

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        document = executor.submit(createPDF, pdfValues)

    #working on something different .... 

    #Here I want to work with the pdf file again, via a new thread
    #Therefore I want to make sure that the thread above is finished.
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        result = executor.submit(workWithPDF, values)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your `document` variable is of type [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future), which has `done()` method that returns `True` if it completed, or [`result()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.result) that returns the result and blocks until it ready (if it still isn't)